# cannot get http response status in angular httpClient

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I have a post request sent to an API endpoint from angular app. I've used Observable but i dont have headers or status property in the reponse im getting in pipe() function. What could be the issue ?

```
public verifyAuth(username: string, password: string): Observable<Credential[]> {
    const headers = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      })
    };
   ///////some variable assignments
    )


    return this.http.post<Credential[]>(this.url, body, headers).pipe(
      map( response => {
        console.log('res headers',response)
        return response;
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        return throwError('Error in Authentication parameters');
      })
    );
```

i have also tried this :

```
 return this.http.post<Credential[]>(this.url, body, {headers, observe: 'response'}).pipe(
      map( response => {
        console.log('res headers',response.headers)
        return response;
      }),
```

the whole code becomes underlined in red and the headers property doesn't exist

Comment: can you provide stackblitz link ?

Comment: have to subscribe ;)

Answer (score 0):

`httpClient.post()` returns a cold Observable, which means nothing will happen  until you `subscribe()` to it.

It will also mean that each `subscribe()` will trigger another call.